# Python3 - TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, plot, knn

I want to make a plot that shows the missclassification error versus de K neighbors using KNN.

This the code i've built for that:

```
# creating odd list of K for KNN
myList = list(range(1,50))

# subsetting just the odd ones
neighbors = filter(lambda x: x % 2 != 0, myList)

# empty list that will hold cv scores
cv_scores = []

# perform 10-fold cross validation
for k in neighbors:
    knn = KNN(n_neighbors=k, n_jobs = 6, metric = 'minkowski', contamination = 0.05)
    scores = cross_val_score(knn, X_test, pred, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')
    cv_scores.append(scores.mean())

### Create Plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')

# changing to misclassification error
MSE = [1 - x for x in cv_scores]

# determining best k
optimal_k = neighbors[MSE.index(min(next(iter(MSE))))]
print ("The optimal K neighbors number is %d" % optimal_k)

# plot misclassification error vs k
plt.plot(neighbors, MSE, figsize = (20,12))
plt.xlabel('Number of Neighbors K')
plt.ylabel('Misclassification Error')
plt.show()
```

The problem is at this line:

```
optimal_k = neighbors[MSE.index(min(next(iter(MSE))))]
```

This code seemed to be written in python 2. This was the original line:

```
optimal_k = neighbors[MSE.index(min(MSE))]
```

I added `next()` and `iter()` to solve this issue, as adviced by some usersin other threads similar to this. But i'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

I know why this error is happening, it should be iterting through a list but it's taking only the numbers. I think the problem comes from the `filter()` use at this line:

```
neighbors = filter(lambda x: x % 2 != 0, myList)
```

How can i fix this code to run on python 3 and prevent this from happening??

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

The KNN version i'm using is not the one in sklearn, for those who would like to try this code. It comes from an anomaly detetction package called PYOD. Link [here](https://pyod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyod.models.html#module-pyod.models.knn)

You can also try it with the original KNN from sklearn, but note you will need to remove the contamination parameter and maybe the distance parameter

Comment: `next(iter(MSE))` returns _a number_. `min(<one single number>)` makes zero sense and thus is an error. Also, when given a single argument, `min` assumes that it's an iterable, but it's a single number in your case. BTW, what was wrong with the original `MSE.index(min(MSE))`?

Comment: @ForceBru What you say makes sense, but this code works in Python 2, so i don't think there's an error, it's just a problem of how to make things work in python 3

Comment: Clearly, calculating the minimum of _a single number_ is an error, so is `min(next(iter(MSE)))`. You say you "added `next()` and `iter()` to solve this issue". What was the original issue? You couldn't index into `neighbors` in Python 3, right?

Comment: `neighbors[MSE.index(min(MSE))]` is a correct syntax. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: @ForceBru this was the original error using the original line of code `'filter' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @Mstaino the syntax is correct but the code won't work in python 3 since the `neighbors` variable was created using `filter` and in python 3 `filter` don't return an interator as it does in python 2

Comment: then use `neighbors = list(neighbors)`

Comment: @Miguel2488, yep, [here's why](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) and [here's how to solve it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html#2to3fixer-filter)

Comment: @Mstaino that solved that error but gave a `list index out of range` error

Comment: Did you put the `neighbors = list(neighbors)` at the beginning? Once the iterator is exhausted it doesn't produce anything. Try `neighbors = list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 != 0, myList))`

Comment: @Mstaino i'm gonna try that and report

Comment: Hi @Mstaino. It worked perfectly and with a huge time optimization and performance, before this code ran for over 45 minutes more or less, now it takes barely 2 minutes. If you can post this as an answer i will be vwry glad to accept it!! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Glad it worked. I posted it as answer as required. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the code is defining `neighbors` as a generator and exhausting it in the first loop. Solution: use a list.

```
neighbors = list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 != 0, myList))
```

Also your original syntax for getting the optimal was correct (no need for `iter` or `next`):

```
optimal_k = neighbors[MSE.index(min(MSE))]
```